# Add two properties to <select>

Tags: html, select

I have this code:

```
<select name="property_category" id="property_category" class="in-field field width">
<option value=""><?php echo apply_filters('epl_search_widget_label_any',__('Any', 'epl') ); ?></option>
```

Now it uses `property_category`. I want to add another one: `property_category1`, so that it uses both names. Can someone help me with the code?
Thanks!

Comment: Why would you need it to have two names?

Comment: If i could use one name I wouldn't ask here. It is a drop-down menu and I need it to show the results from both: property_category and property_category1

Answer (score 2):

As per you question I think you are looking for [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes)

```
<select name="property_category" data-property="category1" id="property_category" class="in-field field width">
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to add these as options? If so, you create a

```
<select name="property_category" id="property_category" class="in-field field width">
<option name="property_category" value="">Option1</option>
<option name="property_category1" value="">Option2</option>
</select>
```

I'm not sure about what your doing or what he php is doing.

Comment: I think, that he's getting the data from a database and wants to put it into a option tag

Comment: Actually this is the whole code:
<?php
$arr = array();
$meta_vals = epl_get_meta_values( 'property_category', $post_type, 'publish' );
if(!empty($meta_vals)) {
$arr = epl_listing_load_meta_property_category();
if(!empty($arr)) {
foreach($arr as $k=>$v) {
if(!in_array($k, $meta_vals)) {
unset($arr[$k]);
}
}
}
}
?>
<select name="property_category" id="property_category" class="in-field field-width">
<option value=""><?php echo apply_filters('epl_search_widget_label_any',__('Any', 'epl') ); ?></option>
</select>

Comment: I just want to add property_category1 to this.

Answer (score 0):

Is 'property_category' the ACTUAL name you are using? I'm not sure I'm getting your idea.

You can make labels for the select tag.
Or just type it loosely if you want to 'name' the select box.

```
   <!--previous HTML code-->
    Property category
<select name="property_category"><option <!-- php code -->></option></select>
Property category 1
<select name="property_category1"><option <!-- php code -->></option></select>
```